# Is there a way to check if a node already exists in graphviz?

Tags: python, graphviz

I am working on drawing trees from given data. However, the way the data is imported causes extra trees to be drawn sometimes from nodes that I don't want to exist. Is there a way to check to see if a node exists?

I haven't been able to find anything helpful on stackoverflow

Comment: Which library do you use to draw your graph? In pygraphviz graph has a `nodes()` method which returns list of nodes. And respective `edges()` and `subgraphs()` methods

Answer (score 0):

Try using a python dictionary to keep your nodes in, and check before trying to add a GraphViz node.  This relies on your being able to identify some key (here called `key1`) that is unique enough to let you decide if the node has already been added.

```
thisdict = {}  # declare a dictionary

# get some node data in some kind of input loop or whatever...
if key1 in thisdict:  # check if key exists
    pass
else:  # key doesn't exist so add it
    thisdict[key1] = "node data goes here"
    # add your GraphViz node here...
```

By checking before adding again, you gain control over what you add.

Comment: How do I put my nodes in a python dictionary?

Comment: @RyanWigglesworth Without seeing a sample of your data, I can only guess.  But I edited my answer to show how you might add to an empty dictionary in some kind of input loop and then check for existence before adding it... hope this helps more.